# LinkedIn Groups API: retrieve comments to questions?

Tags: api, linkedin-api

I can understand from this page: https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/groups-api
that it's only possible to retreive information from the Groups API having an authenticated group member to do it through.

What I need to is periodically retrieve the comments to a particular question posted to the group, not necessarily by my own user.

So I was thinking if it was possible to programmatically authenticate a user (that is member of the group) and through that user retrieve the Group information I need.

Do any of you have experience with that or know of any other way of doing this without having a user authenticated through the webbased linkedin login?

Kind regards,
David

Comment: Authenticating a user so that your application can access data from their LinkedIn network requires manual user input - how would you automate this?

Comment: Well, that was exactly my question. I thought there would be a way to do this. I've read about some hacks, but I understand now that it's not possible without trying to find loop holes in the current API.